# Is this sentence correct? Make vs Made

Tags: verbs

"Your kindness has (and will continue to) ***made*** a difference."

Comment: This would be correct: "Your kindness has **made** and will continue to **make** a difference."

Answer (score 9):

This sentence is an attempt at parallelling, where a sentence branches into two or more parts. In this case, it also rejoins at the end. The parallelled part must join on to the common part in the same way. If you are unsure how to do this, the best way is to write out the parts as complete sentences:

> Your kindness has made a difference
>   Your kindness continues to make a difference.

You can then combine these sentences by eliminating the duplicated word sequences: "Your kindness" from the start and "a difference" from the end.

> Your kindness has made, and will continue to make, a difference.

You cannot eliminate make/made because they are not the same in the two sentences.

Answer (score 3):

No, that sentence is incorrect because "continue to" requires an infinitive after it, and "made" is a past participle (forming part of the present perfect, in this case).

You can say:

- Your kindness has made and will continue to **make** a difference.
- Your kindness has made, and will continue to **make**, a difference.
- Your kindness has made -- and will continue to **make** -- a difference.

Comment: The second sentence sounds more German than English to me.

Answer (score 0):

I like to find the simplest way to say things. You can thank a person for their past, present, and future kindness all at once:

> Your kindness always makes a difference!

I added an exclamation point too. When you're thanking or complimenting someone, you want to sound peppy and upbeat.

Answer (score -1):

I guess he did not intent to include "(and will continue to)" in to the sentence.
He just want to ask if this sentence is present perfect continuous.

and i think, yes it is.